"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe"
I have hosted my API on a web server on which there is internet restriction and I want to send a notification using Firebase Cloud messaging.
Without Internet access to Firebase website, using FCM service which will send message using FCM so without internet access, will it work?
I have setup firebase messaging in my API and also debug to check that Firebase background service is getting called.
private readonly FirebaseMessaging _messaging;
string response = await _messaging.SendAsync(message);

But gives below error:

Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.", Uri:""

I have updated the Device Token but still same error and I think problem is not related to the token.
